Must a number pass both the $\!\!\pmod7$ and $\!\!\pmod9$ test to prove it is not a perfect cube?
I have come across this question in my textbook.

Prove that $a^3+b^3+5$ is not a perfect cube for any integer $a$ and
$b$.

The first thing to come to my mind were the $\pmod 7$ and $\pmod 9$ tests (any perfect cube $\equiv0,1,-1 \pmod{7,9}$ I had been taught so I started with $\pmod 9$ and came to the conclusion that all possibilities $\{3,5,4,6,7\}$ fail therefore it cannot be a perfect cube.
However then I tried $\pmod7$ and it resulted the possibilities $\{0,4,5,6\}$ passing the test which according to what I was taught means that $a^3+b^3+5$ can be a perfect cube for some integers $a$ and $b$ contradicting my original conclusion and the question.
I presume it is not a trick question hence I must have gone wrong somewhere, yet I am not quite sure where, must a perfect cube pass both tests and not just one? I may have simply misunderstood my teachers explanation.

@JonathanZ Thank you for bringing my error to my attention, I have edited my post.

Might be better to use the built-in $\pmod{7}$ to obtain $\pmod{7}$, though that does introduce new spacing issues. Or you could use just (mod $7$), yielding (mod $7$).

Hint: such modular cube tests are necessary, but not sufficient. $\ \ $

What your teacher told you was (I'm guessing!) that

any perfect cube must be 0, 1, or -1, mod 7."

That's very different from
2 "Any number that is $0, 1,$ or $-1$ mod $7$ is actually a perfect cube."
To see this, consider the number $15$. Now $15 \bmod 7 = 1$, but you can see that despite that, $15$ is not a perfect cube!
To get back to your question, you managed (somehow) to show that $a^3 + b^3 + 5$, taken mod 9, was never 0, 1, or -1. Using fact 1 (which is actually true!) you can conclude that $a^3 + b^3 + 5$ is never a perfect cube.
If you apply the same test mod 7, what you end up with "From this test, all I can conclude is that $a^3 + b^3 + 5$ might or might not be a perfect cube." All that tells you is that this particular test is not very useful for this question. Some other test (like the mod 9 one) might very well be more useful and give you an answer that tells you something.
It's like checking witnesses at a crime scene: you ask Jerry, who says "I didn't see anything because a tall guy was in front of me". You ask Robin, who says "I was looking my phone." You ask Chen, who says "I saw Eddie shoot the other guy and the other guy fell down dead on the pavement". Just because Robin and Jerry didn't tell you anything useful doesn't mean Eddie isn't a killer!

Thank you for clarifying, I now understand where I went wrong, and your humorous analogy.

That’s not what the test says. The test says that if a number is a perfect cube then it is $0,1,$ or $-1$  mod $7$. What it does not say is that if a number is $0,1,-1$ mod $7$ then it is a cube. So just because a number is $0,1$ or $-1$ mod $7$ does not mean it’s a cube. So there is no contradiction.
In particular, just because $A$ implies $B$ does not mean $B$ implies $A$.
